# How can I execute a program from my VS2008/C++ application in windows that replaces the caller and runs on xp/vista/7?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

My application downloads updates from a server. After downloading it runs updater.exe (which is set to run with administrative rights) so it can copy the update foo.exe over my application. Since you can't replace the file while it runs the helper application is necessary.

I am making the following system call to run it:
      result=_execl(updaterexe,updaterstr,updateFilestr,exeFilestr,exeFilestr,NULL);

The parameters contained:

c:\program files\foo\updater.exe "c:\program files\foo\updater.exe" "c:\downloads\newfoo.exe" ""c:\program files\foo\foo.exe"

Under vista this works as expected. 
Under windows 7 it returns error code 22 which is invalid parameter. I have also tried quoting the first parameter to no avail. Suspecting that maybe the old _execl was not supported on windows 7 I tried adjusting all the parameters and calling _wexecl but with no change in behaviour.

Can anyone suggest a correction to the call I'm making or suggest a different system call that will work consistently between versions of windows?

Comment: any luck fixing your problem?  The point I was trying to make is that there are at least three good alternatives to "_execl" for running an external program.

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of other alternatives, any of which would work from Windows 95 up:

- CreateProcess() // Recommended Win32 API
- ShellExecute ()
- system ()

Comment: But it's an option, twerp ;)  It's also easy, and it's portable.

Comment: Sure, it's an "option". Just like deliberately causing UB and hoping for it to do what you want is an "option".